# I have three android projects that share many identical or very similar classes. What could I do to make single edits?

Tags: java, android, api, jar, shared-libraries

I have three projects on Android that have many identical or similar classes.
Since I found myself making double or triple changes, I was wondering what could I do to make single edits.

I came up with the following solutions:

- Writing my "own API" and adding it to my android projects. However I would need to export the jar and import the updated one every time I make a change since I don't want to put it on GitHub.
- Loading and compiling those classes at runtime (Reflection). I could for instance load those classes on a server.
- I was thinking maybe about creating an Android library but would be the same thing of creating a jar, right?

Or what else could I do? Thank you.

Comment: Your IDE may support this sort of library directly.  For example NetBeans you can include another project directly as a library, and ask the IDE to copy the .class files into the main project so that there's no separate Jar file to deal with.

Comment: If the three projects are not too different you could make one Android project and implement each app as a flavor dimension. That would allow to have the common code in the regular part that is not assigned to a flavor.

Answer (score 0):

An [Android Library](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) is not the same than a Jar file. Depending on what you are doing an Android Library (reusing Android components) or a jar library (reusing only Java code) would be appropriate.

Comment: Therefore a jar would be more appropriate to load and compile those classes at runtime using Java Reflection?

Comment: That's a design decision you need to make. I don't know all the details of your project and requirements. Usually reflection is used to implement extensions/plugins that need to be loaded at runtime. If you just want to share some Java code between your project you can just use the jars at build time.